# Oracle Sequences MaxValue

Tags: oracle11g

This should be an easy question for the Oracle experts out there.
I have a column, (for example ID NUMBER(10) and I use an Oracle sequence to generate the next
value. According to this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm
a sequence can generate a max value of 28 digits. What I would like to know
is what happens when enough sequences have been generated to reach the max
size of the above column and in the sequence definition I specify CYCLE but
I don't specify a MAXVALUE. Does Oracle handle this in a smart way and start from 
the beginning or do I have to specify that otherwise Oracle will keep on generating
numbers larger than what can be stored in the ID column mentioned above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no relationship between the sequence and the `ID` column-- it is perfectly possible to have one sequence that is used to generate keys for multiple different tables.  That means that the sequence has no idea how you have declared the `ID` column.  If you do not specify a `MAXVALUE`, the sequence will happily continue generating numbers up to 10^27.

If you want the sequence to cycle when it hits 10^11 rather than 10^27, you would need to specify a `MAXVALUE` of 10^11 - 1.